# Passing data from rails 4 to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I would like to pass values from Rails to javascript function. Im using:

```
var data = JSON.parse('<%= @people.pluck(:id) %>');
```

This is working when I pluck on id. When I put

```
var data = JSON.parse('<%= @people.pluck(:name) %>');
```

I got errors and its not working. How can I fix that? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are calling `JSON.parse`, you need to send it a JSON string.  People.id is an integer and People.name is likely a simple string, not formatted using JSON.  What JSON do you have represented in your model that you think needs parsing?

Comment: in the same file? what do you see when you inspect your browser plucking name?

Comment: What errors you got? Please update your post.

Answer (score 0):

Since (almost) all JSON is valid javascript you can simply output JSON from Rails into a javascript variable:

```
var data = <%= @people.pluck(:name).to_json %>;
```

This output will be something like:

```
var data = ['Moe', 'Larry', 'Curly'];
```